# mysqli_fetch_array : undefined index when selecting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

mySQL was doing fine until mySQLi was created :/

I've used mysql_fetch_array() before. However, when I use mysqli_fetch_array() {Notice "i"}, there is a problem getting results from an ASSOCIATIVE array when selecting from multiple tables. That is,

```
$query = "SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM t1, t2 WHERE ...";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
//if num of rows check...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ $first_id = $row['t1.id']; $second_id = $row['t2.id']; }
```

And, I'd get an error: Undefined index: t1.id (or t2.id).

Queries work fine if  I was only selecting from t1 or t2 (not both) or if I was saying $row['id']; instead of $row['t1.id']; but then that **doesn't help in getting different fields from two tables with identical names**

Please help.

Thanks! =)

Comment: Use aliases for the fields. I didn't even know that mysql allowed to specify `t1.id` as array index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has problems separating t1.id and t2.id, the result will return them both as 'id'.

Try renaming/aliasing the column(s) using `AS` in the query instead;

```
$query = "SELECT t1.id AS t1id, t2.id AS t2id FROM t1, t2 WHERE ...";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
//if num of rows check...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ $first_id = $row['t1id']; $second_id = $row['t2id']; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was it. I just realized that unlike mysql_result mysqli_fetch_array isn't capable of accessing fields with same names. So, either one can use "AS" keyword (as you suggested) or one can use numerical indexes (numerical array). I believe it's ridiculously stupid if one compares the traditional mysql_result() with mysqli (i = improved ), yeah sure. Thanks, again for your timely help!

Comment: "If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last column will take precedence and overwrite the earlier data. In order to access multiple columns with the same name, the numerically indexed version of the row must be used. " [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)